# Creating a .NET page to embed other .NET pages

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created certain functionalities for an application. These functionalities include -

1. ADD USER
2. EDIT USER
3. DELETE USER and so on

Now I have written all these in seperate pages. So when I have to delete a user I go to `USER_DELETE.aspx` page to do that.

My new requirement is that there should be a single page from which all these can be done. Being more specific, I want that there should be separate panels in a page called "USER_MANAGER". Each panel will have the required functionality.

Is there a way I can do this by just creating the new UI of the USER_MANAGER page and calling the other pages (as User Controls or any other easier way) into the UI of USER_MANAGER?

I don't want to do any changes to the existing pages for various functions. I hope the question is clear, I am a bit novice in this technology so I am not really sure.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to turn your pages in to ASP.NET [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx). User Controls are just as easy to create as pages and can be used in similar fashion as Server Controls. If you want to create controls that can be shared between projects, then you want to write [Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx) but thos cases are probably not so common.

Comment: yeah pretty much...thats what i am finally going to do. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to tackle this problem.  If you are listing the users in a gridview you could use inline editing and do it within there.

You could retain the pages you wrote and use a modal popup or iframe.  Another way would be with a multiview or tabs or panels.

I would design the UI and the then decide what the best solution for your application is then write these elements.

Comment: panels seems to be the way to go...I have decided to do it the hard way. Create panels for each function and copy the UI parts that are required in the new consolidated page. A bit of a hard work and non innovative  but with the time crunch i m facing it seems to be a plausible choice